# Avoid black loading screen <video> html5/javascript

Tags: javascript, css, video, html5-video, chromecast

I am currently working on a project for chromecast and ran into a problem. 
When I am loading a very short video, the (videoplayer?) screen goes black while loading.
All the video's backgrounds are white and I am switching videos quite often. Therefor, it would look a lot nicer with a white loading background.

I've tried creating a white  and letting it fade out to opacity 0 on event listeners (played, loaded,..). Tried the same with a bit of a delay using setTimeout(..), but there always remains at least a short "pop of black" when switching to the actual video. Also using video's "poster" attribute (by just using a white image..) doesn't prevent this.Furthermore, the natural things like background-color or color attribute's of the video tag are all set to #FFFFFF via css.

Is there any actual way to do so, which I didnt think of yet?

Basically it only needs to work on Chrome (i think chromecast is using some derivative, webkit thing).

```
<canvas id="whiteoverlay"></canvas>
<video id="receiverVideoElement" loop poster="white.png"></video>
```

I'd love if you have some kind of tipp for me or reason why it will never work.

Comment: Normally you could style the background-color of a video element by setting it's `background-color` property by css. Is it possible that you're css file finished loading after the video finished to load? To check this you could set the background-color property directly on the element with `style="background-color:#FFFFFF"`. If this is working, that's your problem.

Comment: thanks @morten.c , but this didnt work. The solution was to do the overlay fading in the suspended eventlistener.

now I basically have the same problem when switching a the video ( to a different one). Gotta figure out that one too.

Comment: You could create a fiddle, then other people (like me) could have a look at it. Good luck and don't forget to post your solution as answer if you find one.

Comment: as already mentioned, no solution was found to avoid the black screen when "switchign to a next video". But for the loading delay of the first one, the suspended listener works pretty well with fading out a white canvas overlay.